# List of (nearly) equal columns from a data.frame by condition in R

Tags: r, filter, dataframe, subset

#### First without the details

I have `data.frame`s like that one:

```
  val1 val2 val3 val4 val5
1  1.1    2  1.1  2.1  4.2
2  5.7    5  5.6  4.9  9.9
3  3.1    3  3.2  2.9  5.9
4  9.6    1  9.5  1.0  2.0
```

and want to get the (nearly) equal rows. The desired result would be something like

```
[1] "val1" "val2" "val5"
```

because the column `val3` is almost equal to `val1`, `val4` is almost equal to `val2` and `val5` is different.

#### Details:

- What does "nearly" equal mean (just one of the options listed below):

  - the absolute difference of the values is smaller than a fixed number (0.2 for the sample above)
  - the relative difference of the values is smaller than a fixed number (~11% for the sample)
  - other metrics which make sense ;-)
- a listing of linearly dependent columns would be even better (but I think that's way more complicated) (that would mean that `val5` is also part of the group which is formed by `val2` and `val4` since it's roughly twice the value)
- it has not to be really fast, `O(n^2)` would be okay. (my frames are only about 12 rows and 300 columns)
- if that should not be possible, a list of exactly equal columns would somehow work, too. Then I would apply the `round()` function before

Comment: Will you accept solutions using arrays?  Your data looks like array data, anyway, since all of the columns have the same class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not quite well-defined how to choose which rows are equal; for instance, you could have three columns where A and B are "equal" and B and C are "equal" but A and C are not.  What to do then?  One way around that might be to use hierarchical clustering, maybe like this:

Using the data from Andrie's answer, first transpose it and make it into a matrix; I'll also standardize each row (what was a column) as a start at finding linear combinations; this will group rows that are exact multiple of each other but not more complex combinations.

```
d <- t(as.matrix(d))
s <- rowSums(d)
ds <- sweep(d, 1, s, `/`)
```

We now make a tree, and for interest, plot it.  This uses the default distance function (Euclidean) but others are possible.

```
tree <- hclust(dist(ds))
plot(tree)
```

[image: plot of tree from hclust]

We then choose where to cut the tree into groups (this is where you choose how close two have to be to be "equal"); I output it together with the sum of values to see if any are multiples of another.

```
> grp <- cutree(tree, h=0.1)
> cbind(grp, s)

     grp    s
val1   1 19.5
val2   2 11.0
val3   1 19.4
val4   2 10.9
val5   2 22.0
```

Comment: Nice answer.  I considered cluster and factor analysis, but one has to be careful to specify the standardisation (i.e. `scale`) correctly.  Otherwise columns with a fixed offset difference will fall into the same cluster.

Comment: About the well-definedness: You're quite right, it's not well defined. Since this is only a preprocessing, I prefer building more groups instead of grouping unrelated values.

Comment: Yes, more complex answers might have to worry about an offset not mattering when it should, but I don't think this one does; the Euclidean distance calculation should do the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

Replicate your data:

```
structure(list(val1 = c(1.1, 5.7, 3.1, 9.6), val2 = c(2L, 5L, 
3L, 1L), val3 = c(1.1, 5.6, 3.2, 9.5), val4 = c(2.1, 4.9, 2.9, 
1), val5 = c(4.2, 9.9, 5.9, 2)), .Names = c("val1", "val2", "val3", 
"val4", "val5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4"))
x
  val1 val2 val3 val4 val5
1  1.1    2  1.1  2.1  4.2
2  5.7    5  5.6  4.9  9.9
3  3.1    3  3.2  2.9  5.9
4  9.6    1  9.5  1.0  2.0
```

Create a function.  The mechanism is to wrap around the base R function `duplicated` which has a method for arrays that also handles columns, unlike the method for data.frames that only handles rows.  Also, I took you at your word and round each column, but you can specify the number of digits as a parameter.

```
not_duplicated <- function(x, round_digits, margin=2){
  x2 <- apply(x, margin, round, round_digits)  
  colnames(x)[!duplicated(x2, MARGIN=margin)]
}
```

The results are as you specified:

```
x <- as.matrix(x)
not_duplicated(x, 0)
[1] "val1" "val2" "val5"
```